# After changing a webform multi-select field to single-select, submissions made pre-change show only the first selection

Tags: 7, webforms

I've created a webform in Drupal 7 with a component drop-down list.  I selected 'multiple' for multiple selections.  Now, I need to unselect 'multiple' giving users just one choice of the drop-down list.

Now, when viewing the submission data, the past data w/ multiple choices only show the topmost choice.  How can I have the past data show the multiple choices despite I'm allowing only one choice in the component?

Comment: Depends on if the webform submissions in the database has been updated, if they have, then it's not possible.

Comment: For the component, if I switch back to 'multiple', the data chosen reappears in the submission view.  So..., the data is still there.  When 'multiple' is turned off, it just shows the 'top' choice, only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the field set to single choice, and use `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` to display the values as if it was still a multi-select field.

You can use the hook in a module or the `template.php` of a theme. If you are thinking about implementing it in a theme, keep in mind that the `Webform Results` view is displayed through the Administration theme. So, the hook must be implemented in the default administration theme for it to work in that view. By implementing it in a module, you shouldn't have to worry about which theme the submission results are being shown.

You will need the `nid` for the webform, and the `form Key` for the select field. The nid is in the url of the webform's edit page. The `form key` can be seen in the webform's `Form components`page.

The following code is implemented in the "my_module" module, for a webform with a `nid` of "100", and a field with the `form key` "my_select_field".

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_render_alter().
 */
function my_module_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) {
  if ($renderable['#node']->nid == '100' && isset($renderable['my_select_field'])) {
    $renderable['my_select_field']['#multiple'] = 1;
  }
}
```

The `isset($renderable['my_select_field'])` in the if statement may seem redundant, but it's there to prevent an exception if someone changes the `form key` for the field.

Comment: Excellent solution, we'll give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

You could instead create a new component for the single choice option, and disable the multi-option one.